# My code works on terminal but not on CLion

Tags: c++, data-structures, clion

```
struct Patient_Record {
    char name[20], doctorName[20], diagnosis[20];
    int patientNumber, polyclinicNumber;
    char branchName[20];
};
```

first file

```
main(){

    defter.file_to_array();

    defter.print();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

second file

I have four seperate files and three of them here.Rest of them is unnecessary.

```
void Dizi::file_to_array() {
        ifstream file("database.txt");
        std::string line;

     while(std::getline(file,line)){//reading file line by line

        std::istringstream ss(line);
         std::string token;


         std::getline(ss, token, '\t');     //parsing line strings into the variables of the structures
        strncpy(k[kayitsayisi].name,token.c_str(), sizeof(token));


        std::getline(ss, token, '\t');
        strncpy(k[kayitsayisi].doctorName, token.c_str(), sizeof(token));


        std::getline(ss, token, '\t');
        strncpy(k[kayitsayisi].diagnosis, token.c_str(), sizeof(token));


        std::getline(ss, token, '\t');
        k[kayitsayisi].patientNumber = atoi(token.c_str());

        std::getline(ss, token, '\t');
        k[kayitsayisi].polyclinicNumber= atoi(token.c_str());

        std::getline(ss, token, '\t');
        strncpy(k[kayitsayisi].branchName,token.c_str(), sizeof(token));


        kayitsayisi++;

    }

    }



    void Dizi::print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < kayitsayisi; i++){
            cout << i + 1 << ". " <<(p+i)->name<<'\t'<<(p+i)->doctorName<<'\t'<<(p+i)->diagnosis<<'\t';
            cout<<(p+i)->patientNumber<<'\t'<<(p+i)->polyclinicNumber<<'\t'<<(p+i)->branchName<<endl;
        }
    }
```

third file

Problem is my code does work on VS 2015,windows terminal and ubuntu terminal. But it does not work on Clion. It compiles successfuly but nothing happens after that. Is it a bug or something?

Comment: Maybe it's displayed and closed so fast you can't see the result

Comment: No it's not , i tried with cin just before return success.

Comment: Well, then you have to use debugger. For example here is some [intro](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/05/debug-clion/)

Comment: If you can share the full project with our support (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us), we will be glad to check what's going on there for you. It's a bit hard to guess by a small pieces of code without a full picture.